# Generic method with stack

Tags: java, generics, stack

my code:

```
    public static void spilledOn (Stack<Object> st1,Stack<Object> st2){
    while (!st2.isEmpty()){
            st1.push(st2.pop());
    }    
}

public static int findLengthInStack (Stack<Object> st1){
    Stack<Object> tmp=new Stack<>();
    int count=0;
    while (tmp.isEmpty()){
        tmp.push(st1.pop());
        count++;
    }
    toolsForAnything.spilledOn(st1, tmp);
    return count;
}
```

when I call this method and I use another type of stack its not working well
(I mean I use `Stack<Integer>`) 
Does anyone have any solution for this ?
(I hope its right that I use with object)

Comment: Please post [mcve] to show exactly what is "not working well".

Comment: `public class Stack<E> extends Vector<E>` has a method `size`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really wanted to use this algorithm for some reason, then for a general `Stack` you would need to declare a type parameter for each method.

```
// (Really an API would be using super and extends here,
//   but let's keep it simple.)
public static <T> void spilledOn (Stack<T> st1,Stack<T> st2){
    //        ^^^                       ^            ^
[...]
// (I'm using a different name (E vs T) here
//     just to illustrate that I am declaring two variables.
//   Using the same letter would be more conventional.)
public static <E> int findLengthInStack (Stack<E> st1){
    //        ^^^                              ^
    Stack<E> tmp=new Stack<>();
    //    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the (unnecessary) method to find how many elements are in the stack, you can do it like this:

```
public class Helper {

    private static <T> int findSize(Stack<T> input) {
        return input.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
        stack.push(4);
        stack.push(9);

        System.out.println(findSize(stack));

    }
}
```

Why I said *unnecessary*? Because you can simply write:

```
System.out.println(stack.size());
```

instead of:

```
System.out.println(findSize(stack));
```

Comment: Please, notice that you have to write <T> before the return type of the method... Just see in the answer: `private static <T> int findSize(Stack<T> input)`. Static keyword isn't necessary, but I wrote this so it can be called without `Helper helper = new Helper();`...

Comment: i saw that and i think its my solution

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, you might consider to accept it and/or vote up, so the other users of this site can benefit from it.

Comment: what the <T> before the return type is actually do?

Comment: Well, in short, <T> before returning type is resolving <T> in the parameter of the method.